# "After taking a rest, I get ready for job"

Tags: infinitives, construction

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> After taking a rest, I get ready for job.

I think the statement above sounds informal.  I'm also unclear as to what it means.

Would English native speakers understand this phrase, is it clear? Should I say the following instead?

> After taking a rest, I **be** ready for job.

Comment: Please explain where your confusion lies. Why do you think this sentence might be **incorrect** or **ungrammatical** (in grammar we don't say a sentence is "true"). Otherwise [your question is off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and you are asking us to proofread, a service which is usually paid for. Please, edit your post, if you wish your question to be answered

Comment: I think this statement is informal or dose not have a obvious meaning. Does this statement have a obvious meaning for folk talk(daily use)? Thank you very much.

Comment: for example I think I can use 'I be ready...' instance of 'I get ready...' . If no, why?

Comment: Please **edit** your post. Comments are usually for users who ask for clarification. However, your first comment seems to suggest that you have read this sentence somewhere.  If this is the case, can you say *where*? Your second comment explains better your confusion, and no longer makes your question a proofreading one. :)

Comment: Dear Mari-Lou , I have not read this sentence anywhere. I am a student of the English language and  I'm practicing with my friends. Does this statement have a obvious meaning? thank you.

Comment: By editing I meant the above. Please, change, adapt or add anything to help users answer your question. You might need to wait a bit, please don't disappear. Come back after a few hours, and if you still see nothing you can *ping* me by: @[username]. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a native English speaker the sentence:

> After taking a rest, I get ready for job.

has a vague but obvious meaning.  However, it has a grammatical error that a claim to be "informal" can't justify.  `Job` requires an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)) the same as `rest` required `a` (an article).

> After taking **a** rest, I get ready for **a** job.
>
> After taking **a** rest, I get ready for **my** job.
>
> After taking **a** rest, I get ready for **the** job.

However, if **job** were replaced with **work** no article would be required.

> After taking a rest, I get ready for **work**.

The essential difference here is job is a [countable noun](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/countable-uncountable-nouns.htm) and work is not.  I can have two jobs but I can't have two works.  I work or I don't work.

Your "fix" doesn't help.  It actually causes another problem:

> After taking a rest, I *be* ready for job.

This adds another grammatical flaw.  It could mean:

> After taking a rest, I **will be** ready for a job.

Or it could mean:

> After taking a rest, I **[am](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/am)** ready for *a* job.

`am` *verb* 1st person singular **present** indicative of `be`.

Comment: Thank you very much 'CandiedOrange'. Your answer is perfect.

Comment: I think the OP has confused *job* with *work*, it sounds more idiomatic saying: "After taking a rest, I'm ready for work" or "I'm ready to work". It's only a guess of course, but it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA hows this?

Comment: I mean "work" and no "job". I asked this question from my teacher. He had your idea.Thank you dear @Mari-LouA .

Comment: @M.Namjo well thank you for coming back and confirming what was my guess. That was nice of you. Just substitute *a job* with *work* (no article) and CandiedOrange's answer is pretty much perfect.